# How to create the com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key object in the Google App Engine _ah/api/explorer?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, jdo

I have a GAE JDO annotated object:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class HelloGreeting {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key id;

  @Persistent
  private String message;

  ... constructors, getters, setters
}
```

and my own endpoint:

```
public HelloGreeting update(HelloGreeting helloGreeting)
        throws NotFoundException {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        pm.getObjectById(HelloGreeting.class, helloGreeting.getId());
        ... some logic
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return helloGreeting;
}
```

where I would like to send from frontend or from the Google App Engine *_ah/api/explorer* the *helloGreeting* object.

When I create one using `pm.makePersistent(helloGreeting);`, then the *api explorer* shows me something like this:

```
{
 "id": {
   "kind": "HelloGreeting",
   "appId": "project-id",
   "id": "5629499534213120",
   "complete": true
  },
"message": "some text"
}
```

I use then this JSON structure to call the `update(HelloGreeting helloGreeting)` method via the api explorer and I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.getAppId(Key.java:279)
...
...
```

... which was because of line `pm.getObjectById(HelloGreeting.class, helloGreeting.getId());` in my `update(HelloGreeting helloGreeting)` method.

It seems like the *private Key id* field is not unmarshalled correctly.
I tried it also with `pm.getObjectById(HelloGreeting.class, helloGreeting.getId().getId());` but with no success.

**Can somebody please tell me if this is even possible?**

PS: I can't change the type of the *id* field from *Key* to *Long* (which works) because then I wouldn't use inner child object annotated with `@PersistenceCapable`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain about your case, but I think you may need to write a custom [transformer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apitransformer) to make sure the key is reconstructed properly.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer :D

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a bit nasty solution. This is my `update()` endpoint:

```
public HelloGreeting update(HelloGreeting helloGreeting)
        throws NotFoundException {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        if(!containsGreeting(helloGreeting)) {
            throw new NotFoundException("not exists");
        }
        // persisting the helloGreeting with the new Key
        pm.makePersistent(helloGreeting);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return helloGreeting;
}

private boolean containsGreeting(HelloGreeting helloGreeting) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    boolean contains = true;
    try {
        // here I'm creating a new Key from the helloGreeting
        Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(HelloGreeting.class.getSimpleName(), helloGreeting.getId().getId());
        // using the Key for a query
        pm.getObjectById(HelloGreeting.class, key);
        // and rewriting the old incorrect unmarshalled Key by the new one 
        helloGreeting.setId(key);
    } catch (javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException ex) {
        contains = false;
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return contains;
}
```

If somebody knows a better solution, I would appreciate it.